# Fixing line at mirror

Tags: mirror

I've been looking at other mirror issues, they didn't seem to do the job for me or it was wrong. My apologies if it's a double!

I've been trying to resolve an edge in a mirrored object. However, this edge will not go away despite all my attempts to fix it. I've tried aligning all the points along the X-axis by scaling it with 0, didn't work out, as well as removing all other modifiers.

This mirror is part of a much bigger object that I need mirrored, however, this is the only object centered that has to align. Is there a workaround for this?

[image: edge split]

[image: mirror settings]

Comment: Check if you have inner faces

Comment: Does increasing the `merge limit` fix your problem?